# Como executar duas classes de WebSecurity no Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

tenho um projeto que realiza autenticações por meio de JWT Token, e ele utiliza o Swagger, dai eu fiz uma página de login e cadastro para fazer a autenticação antes de entrar no Swagger, porém eu não queria fazer a autenticação por meio de tokens, então decidi criar outra classe de configuração para fazer assim a autenticação, porém elas estão dando conflito, alguém tem alguma ideia de como faço para usar duas classes de configuração do WebSecurity no mesmo projeto spring?

SpringSecurityConfig

```
package br.com.sinergico.security;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Component
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled=true)
@Order(1)
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    private TokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService;

    private TokenAuthenticationPortadorService tokenAuthenticationPortadorService;

    private PortadorService portadorService;

    private TokenAuthenticationEstabelecimentoService tokenAuthenticationEstabelecimentoService;

    @Autowired
    private UserEstabelecimentoService userEstabelecimentoService;

    public SpringSecurityConfig() {
        super(true);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void teste() {
        tokenAuthenticationService = new TokenAuthenticationService(userService);
        portadorService = new PortadorService();
        tokenAuthenticationPortadorService = new TokenAuthenticationPortadorService(portadorService);
        tokenAuthenticationEstabelecimentoService = new TokenAuthenticationEstabelecimentoService(userEstabelecimentoService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.exceptionHandling().and().anonymous().and().servletApi().and()
                // .headers().cacheControl().and().
                .authorizeRequests()

                //Paths necessários para o Swagger
                .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/swagger-resources/configuration/ui").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/swagger-resources").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/swagger-resources/configuration/security").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/webjars/**").permitAll()

                // All other request need to be authenticated
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()

                // Custom Token based authentication based on the header
                // previously given to the client
                .addFilterBefore(new StatelessAuthenticationFilter(tokenAuthenticationService,tokenAuthenticationPortadorService, tokenAuthenticationEstabelecimentoService),
                        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/v2/api-docs")
                  .antMatchers("/swagger-resources/configuration/ui")
                  .antMatchers("/swagger-resources")
                  .antMatchers("/webjars/**")
                  .antMatchers("/swagger-resources/configuration/security");
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public UserService userDetailsService() {
        return userService;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService() {
        return tokenAuthenticationService;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenAuthenticationPortadorService tokenAuthenticationPortadorService(){
        return tokenAuthenticationPortadorService;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenAuthenticationEstabelecimentoService tokenAuthenticationEstabelecimentoService(){
        return tokenAuthenticationEstabelecimentoService;
    }

}
```

SwaggerSecurityConfig

```
package br.com.sinergico.security;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(2)
public class SwaggerSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

    private final String SWAGGER_ACESSO_QUERY = "select login, senha, status from suporte.swagger_acesso where login=?";
    private final String ROLE_ACESSO_QUERY = "select u.login, r.role from suporte.swagger_acesso u inner join suporte.swagger_acesso_role ur "
            + "on (u.id_usuario = ur.id_usuario) inner join suporte.swagger_role r on (ur.role_id=r.role_id) where u.login=?";

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
          .authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
          .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
          .antMatchers("/signup").permitAll()
          .antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html").authenticated()
          .and().csrf().disable()
          .formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error=true")
          .defaultSuccessUrl("/swagger-ui.html")
          .usernameParameter("login")
          .passwordParameter("senha")
          .and().rememberMe();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
          .jdbcAuthentication()
          .usersByUsernameQuery(SWAGGER_ACESSO_QUERY)
          .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(ROLE_ACESSO_QUERY)
          .dataSource(dataSource)
          .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);

     }
}
```

Está dando o erro de que uma dá conflito na outra, quando eu coloco no "SpringSecurityConfig" = @Order(1) e na outra @Order(2), o SpringSecurityConfig bloqueia todos os métodos que estão permitidos na SwaggerSecurityConfig e se for ao contrário da a mesma coisa.

Comment: Coloca o que você já implementou até agora, e o erro apresentado.

Comment: @GiulianaBezerra Editado